# PowerShell script won't run outside of ISE

Tags: email, powershell

I'm brand new to PowerShell, apologies in advance.  I started with the script found here: [Getting Event Log contents by email](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18227.getting-event-log-contents-by-email-on-an-event-log-trigger.aspx) (huge credit and thanks) and tweaked it to how I needed it to work.  Basically when this error code happens, it posts every 60 seconds, so I only want an email every so often with the 20 most recent events converted to HTML in a basic table. Everything works great when executing the script in ISE, however no email is sent when run in the regular PowerShell console or as a scheduled task. One thing to note, I can run everything up to the Email Section in a PowerShell Console and have it write out to an HTML file `EventID-To-HTML | Out-File -FilePath $filePath -Append`.  Being new, I'm sure I'm not handling things exactly right, so feedback is always appreciated. Thanks so much

```
Clear-Host

# ========================
# Collection Data Section
# ========================

function EventID-To-HTML($ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME) {
    $FROMTIME = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-60)
    $Event = get-eventlog -log Application -newest 20 | where {$_.EventID -eq 7071 -AND $_.TimeGenerated -gt $FROMTIME}
    $eventstring = @()
    Foreach ($i in $Event) {
        $eventstring += $i.Message + ", " +$i.TimeGenerated
    }

    if ($eventstring -eq $NULL){exit}

    $GetEventDate = get-eventlog -log Application -newest 1 | where {$_.EventID -eq 7071 -AND $_.TimeGenerated -gt $FROMTIME}
    $EventDate = $GetEventDate.TimeGenerated

    $htmlStart = "<HTML>
                    <HEAD>
                      <style> 
                        body {background-color:rgb(238, 238, 238);}
                        body, table, td, th {font-family:Calibri; color:Black; Font-Size:11pt}
                                         th {font-weight:bold; background-color:rgb(78, 227, 48);}
                                         td {background-color:rgb(255, 190, 0);}
                      </style>
                    </HEAD>
                  <BODY><div align=center>
                  <h2><b><br><br>Security Alert: <span Style='font-style:normal; color:Blue'>**Camera(s) Down**</span></b></h2>
                  <p><b><br>This event occurred at: <span Style='font-style:italic; color:Blue'>$EventDate on $ComputerName</span></b></p>"

    $htmlEnd = ''
    $htmlStart

    $eventstring | ForEach-Object {Add-Member -InputObject $_ -Type NoteProperty -Name Camera -Value $_; $_} | ConvertTo-Html -Property Camera
    #$eventstring | %{ New-Object PsObject -Prop @{Length = $_.Length; String = $_} } | ConvertTo-HTML

    $htmlStart = ''
    $htmlStart = $htmlStart + "<br><br><br><i><span Style='color:red'>This report has been generated by software</i> <br><i>Please DO NOT reply.</i></div>"
    $htmlStart
    $htmlEnd = ''
    $htmlEnd 
}

# ======================
# Email Section
# ======================

# Make sure $eventstring has something in it first as to not send an empty message
if ($eventstring.count -ge 1) {
    $strFrom = "Sender@domain.com"
    $strTo = "recipient@domain.com"
    $strSubject = "Subject"
    $strSMTPServer = "SMPT Server name"

    $objEmailMessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage
    $objEmailMessage.From = ($strFrom)
    $objEmailMessage.To.Add($strTo)
    $objEmailMessage.Subject = $strSubject
    $objEmailMessage.IsBodyHTML = $true
    $objEmailMessage.Body = EventID-To-HTML

    $objSMTP = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($strSMTPServer)
    $objSMTP.Send($objEmailMessage)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is a scoping issue with $eventstring.  It's being created inside the EventID-To-HTML function.  Because of the way scoping works in the ISE, this variable is still available after the function runs.  Normally a function runs in it's own scope, and when it exist the scope is disposed and it takes all the variables that were created in that scope with it.

You can test that by dot-sourcing the function so it runs in the current scope.

```
. EventID-To-HTML | Out-File -FilePath $filePath -Append
```

Note the space between the dot and the function name.  That has to be there.

One way to avoid that is to use a collection type like array list instead of an aray.

```
$eventstring = new-object collections.arraylist
    Foreach ($i in $Event) {
        $eventstring.add("$($i.Message), $($i.TimeGenerated)") > $nul
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I need some more clarification.  If I make $eventstring in global scope that would, in my mind, seem to fix it, correct?

Comment: You can, but using global variables is generally considered bad practice. There are other ways to aviod the scoping issue.  One is to use an arralist istead of an array.  I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Everything works now except in the Send Email section `If ($eventstring.count -ge 1) {`.  If I comment that out, the email sends, however with that in, no email is sent.  I can verify that the array list does indeed have a count great than 1 earlier in the function.  It's like it looses the array data.